# Redis performance on Windows localhost

Tags: c#, windows, performance, redis

I have a Redis instance installed on my local machine. The instance contains 147,848 serialized objects. I need to retrieve all objects and then apply some logic. I cam to know that there is no way to retrieve all objects at once so first i get all keys as

```
var keys = client.GetAllKeys();
```

and then i iterate through keys to get json and then deserialize them as

```
var keys = client.GetAllKeys();
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    var sobj = client.Get<string>(key);
    MyClass desobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(sobj);
    myList.Add(desobj);
}
```

All this process, getting all keys and then retrieving all objects and deserializing them, takes approx **32 seconds**.

For 0.15 million objects

1. Getting all keys took 0.4 seconds
2. Getting all values took 16 seconds
3. Deserializing took 6 seconds

There is another Redis instance which has 1 million objects and

1. Getting all keys took 2 seconds
2. Getting all values took 64 seconds
3. Deserializing took 29 seconds

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can improve performance by using multiple threads (you can use c# parallel for). Please not that Redis is a single-thread application and the gain of permanence will be on the DeSerializing step.

If I were you I would measure time required to get all keys, all values and deserialize all values. With this information you can understand better what part is most slow.

Comment: Since the bottle neck is in the back and forth round trips to redis, a few thoughts I have are: Can you use an in memory dictionary instead of redis? Can you consolidate values into fewer but larger objects? Can you use multiple redis instance so that readings can be parallelized?